# Куда пушить изменения во время построения проекта в Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-submodule

Суть: есть build ветка, которая собирается в Jenkins'e.
Проект имеет 1 сабмодуль, который может обновиться и в build ветке может/будет находиться информация, что мы находимся на коммите №1 (когда уже написали 2 фичи и сделали 2 коммита).
При инициализации модулей в Jenkins'e мы перепрыгнем на коммит №3 в модуле и появятся изменения (что модуль №1 находится на коммите №3, а не на №1).

**Куда эти изменения коммитить и пушить?** В саму build ветку? Если да, то если Jenkins pipeline настроен на проверку SCM, то Jenkins при повторной проверке изменений в репозитории увидит свой же коммит и начнет пересобирать проект еще раз, что не хотелось бы. Или заводить каждый раз отдельную ветку с, например, текущей датой и временем или завести еще 1 ветку, например "post-build" и пушить изменения в модулях в неё, чтобы потом можно было эти изменения накатить на master?

Вот такое я вижу в Jenkinse сейчас:

```
 > git submodule update --init --recursive --remote modules/test2 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Git commit changes)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $GIT_PASSWORD
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ git status
HEAD detached at 16ea377
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   modules/test2 (new commits)
```

Comment: 1) Не используйте сабмодули 2) ничего не пуште при сборке в Jenkins

Comment: @user7860670 "критикуешь - предлагай", что предложите взамен тому, чтобы одинаковый код шарить между проектами (кроме монорепозитория, это ужас).

Comment: Используйте отдельные, независимые репозитории. А для подтягивания их при сборке - утилита контроля зависимостей. Собственно сабмодули часто и используют как такую утилиту, а потом мучаются.

Comment: @user7860670 Сабмодули и так отдельными репозиториями, как их еще можно использовать по другому? Первый раз слышу про это. Какие дальше могут быть проблемы с сабмодулями?

Comment: Можно подтягивать нужные репозитории без сабмодулей, например плоский или иерархический workspace, когда все проекты имеют один ранг. А проблем с сабмодулями куча. Собственно сабмодули в гите реализованы откровенно костыльными средствами, поверх того, что было. Соответственно средства для работы с ними радикально отличаются от средств по работе с простыми репозиториями. Не будучи средством контроля зависимостей, git совершенно не волнует корректность связей в иерархии сабмодулей, получение и правка этих связей затруднена, циклические зависимости по идее вообще не поддерживаются и т.д.

Comment: @user7860670 не могу найти ни одного примера почему-то, возможно ищу не так, можно пример?

Comment: ¿А пример чего именно?

Comment: @user7860670 "Можно подтягивать нужные репозитории без сабмодулей, например плоский или иерархический workspace, когда все проекты имеют один ранг."